# Are there any string output commands other than Console.Write in C#

Tags: c#

I know C# and I was wondering if there is any built-in commands to output strings other than `Console.Write`. The reason behind this is CodeGolf.SE, Console.writeLine is too long and I hope there is a shorter command so I can submit some short answers there.

Comment: where you want output string?

Comment: Would it be appropriate to create a class-level function to just call `Console.Write[Line]()`?

Comment: If only for programmer, use: Debug.WriteLine("string"); or Debug.Write("string");

Comment: @PakkuDon changed my question, I was hoping for something short, like `cout`

Comment: @HaLaBi you can call `Console.Write` inside your custom shirt name method

Comment: I don't think a custom method is allowed in CodeGolf, otherwise everyone can just put all their code in it and call the method: 4 characters and done! Besides, where do you put the limitations of what is allowed its own method and what isn't? Short answer: no, you're stuck with it.

Comment: There is a specific code-golf site for this kind of nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big gain but using the aliasing feature of the using directive

```
using CL = System.Console
...
CL.WriteLine("Test");
```

But really it doesn't worth the effort, and not to be recommended in real work projects

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
Action<object> w = Console.Write;
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in CodinGame Clash of Code, you can use Console.Write("xxxx") instead of Console.WriteLine("xxxx") if your answer is only one line. It will save your 4 bytes and validators dont check for the final /n.